# how to synchronize my application with system startup (OS)?

Tags: java, calendar

One of my application tasks is to get the current system date and compares it with a stored date in my database,i want to make a thread that runs once the system starts in order to get the current date, in other words i want my application to work in the background once the system is started, how to do that,thanks.

Comment: With system, you mean once the computer starts (the OS) or once the application starts?

Comment: once the computer starts(the OS)

Comment: OS needs to be specified too.

Comment: which OS do you use...!?

Comment: The simplest way I see it, is to create a small utility program that records the date and store in the appropiate location. Then you simply put this program in the autostart folder

Comment: that depends on your os. windows has a taskplaner, linux has runlevels (and other options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html). Its a Windows executable, that allows you to install / uninstall java programs as Windows services.

Installation of the service goes as follows (from the project site):

```
prunsrv //IS//TestService --DisplayName="Test Service" \
    --Classpath=myAwesomeService.jar \
    --Install=prunsrv.exe --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm \
    --StartClass=my.awesome.package.MyStartClass --StartParams=arg1;arg2;arg3 \
    --StopClass=my.awesome.package.MyStopClass --StopParams=arg1#arg2
```

After that, you just start/stop the service using:

```
net start TestService
net stop TestService
```

or using Services view from My Computer.

Your start / stop classes should have `main(String[] args)` methods implemented that will handle starting / stopping of your thread.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Windows service, running the thread inside the Windows service, and setting startup  of the service to Automatic will do the job.